# Is using goto a legitimate way to break out of two loops?

Tags: c++, goto

I am solving problem 9 on the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/). In my solution I use a "goto" statement to break out of two for loops. The Problem is the following:

> A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a  b  c, for which,
>
> a^2 + b^2 = c^2
>
> For example, 3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 52.
>
> There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
> Find the product abc.

My solution is in c++:

```
int a,b,c;
const int sum = 1000;
int result = -1;
for (a = 1; a<sum; a++){
    for (b = 1; b < sum; b++){
            c = sum-a-b;
            if (a*a+b*b == c*c){
                result = a*b*c;
                goto found;
            }
    }   
}
found:
std::cout << "a:" << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b:" << b << std::endl;
std::cout << "c:" << c << std::endl;
std::cout <<"Result:" << result << std::endl;
```

Since "goto" statements are not very popular among c++ programmers, i would like to know, if this could be considered a reasonable use of "goto". Or if there is a better solution for the problem that doesn't need "goto". By that I don't mean a solution which just avoids "goto", but which avoids "goto" in a way that improves the algorithm.

Comment: i love those 8-space tabs you are using....very sexy.

Comment: I just found this on the "Related" sidebar. An interesting thread overall, but in particular, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245742/examples-of-good-gotos-in-c-or-c/245801#245801) is an answer to my question.

Comment: thank you, I like them too :-)

Comment: With a 16-space tab in the middle...

Comment: I see this as reasonable. It is a forward jump. It does not make the code harder to read. Remember readability is the key (that is why goto is not liked; it can make the code hard to follow). But the same affect can be achieved by putting the loops inside a function (passing a,b,c as ref parameters) and using return instead of goto.

Comment: Here's a tip I picked up somewhere: only jump forward, and you'll avoid unreadable spaghetti code.

Comment: Well, you guys know what, I like my tabs as they are! ;-)

Comment: I think the goto is fine here. @Nikhil Chelliah And only jump out, never jump into an inner block.

Comment: @Lulu: where is the code? oh, it's all the way to the right! really, why use 32 spaces when 6 will do?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`return` is a "structured" `goto` which many programmers find more acceptable! So:

```
static int findit(int sum, int* pa, int* pb, int* pc)
{
    for (int a = 1; a<sum; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b < sum; b++) {
            int c = sum-a-b;
            if (a*a+b*b == c*c) {
                *pa = a; *pb = b; *pc = c;
                return a*b*c;
        }
    }
    return -1;    
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c;
    const int sum = 1000;
    int result = findit(sum, &a, &b, &c);
    if (result == -1) {
        std::cout << "No result!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "a:" << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b:" << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c:" << c << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Result:" << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1:  if it's complex enough to consider a goto, it's complex enough to encapsulate in a function and avoid the goto.

Comment: Yep. Don't complicate the loops.Just get out. Perfect solution. But you could pass a,b,c by reference. Then you don't need to mess around with pointers.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution. It doesn't make the code less readable.

Comment: @Lulu, glad you liked it. @Martin, sure, you can use references instead of pointers -- having been with Google for many years now, I tend to mostly like and use our style guide, see http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Argumentsfor more discussion of why and how, anyway the style boils down to "input arguments are values or const references while output arguments are pointers. Input parameters may be const pointers, but we never allow non-const reference parameters".

Comment: @Alex, I agree coding standards are great and should be followed where appropriate. But: They are only guidelines, this is a situation that screams for the use of references. Otherwise you should be checking for NULL!

Comment: @Martin, I prefer the piece of mind that comes from knowing that, whether I'm programming in C or C++, calling f(a) will _never_ alter a -- that peace of mind would disappear if we let it happen "sometimes". And checking if (e.g.) pa is null is as supererogatory as checking that (e.g.) a*a+b*b isn't overflowing -- just part of the contract the caller must respect. Lastly, references can be erroneously null too (receive int&a, pass *p where int *p is 0, just print &a in the receiving function and you'll see the 0)...!-).

Comment: The only downside to this approach is that, in ducking a fight with the "NEVER USE GOTO!!!" crowd, you run straight into a fight with the "FUNCTIONS MUST ONLY HAVE ONE RETURN!!!" crowd. So taking this approach because you like it, feel that "findit" is a good abstraction, and are willing to defend it, is fine. Taking this approach solely in order to avoid a goto is futile.

Comment: @Alex: if you want your function to be a good citizen of the world, then you might consider standard (C) functions like "time()", which allows the outparam to be NULL just in case some caller only needs the return value. If it's a private function which will only ever be called from one place, in order to make the calling function body be fewer loc, then obviously you do whatever. It may well get inlined anyway...

Comment: @onebyone, sure, there's all sort of fundamentalists;-), but "single return"ites are pretty thin on the ground at any place I'd care to work for: differently from gotophobia (a benign ailment which has been observed in excellent programmers, due to being scarred by past encounters with spaghetti code), monoreturnitis is a malignant (though fortunately rare) syndrome requiring drastic therapy...;-)

Comment: @onebyone again, making it `static` to indicate it's not supposed to be called from "outside" is a good idea -- editing the answer now to add that bit.

Comment: Excellent. So all that's left is the battle to the death and blood-feud-to-the-seventh generation, about how multiple return values should be handled. I'm saying you need "class PythagoreanTriple : private boost::tuple<int,int,int>" ;-)

Comment: Personally I like returning tuples (I'm a Python developer after all!-), but "output parameters" have a long and proud tradition (and can save some machine cycles) so I doubt they'll be eradicated from C and C++ any time soon (or ever;-).

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion it's fine to use `goto` in a situation like this.

Btw, the condescending preaching against goto usually comes from people who just parrot what they heard others say or read somewhere..

Comment: Java has named loops, which are pretty much identical to this

Comment: @Casebash: Sure. But how is this related to the answer or the question?

Answer (score 6):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982595/how-to-break-out-of-2-loops-without-a-flag-variable-in-c) about breaking out of 2 loops.  There are much better answers provided than using a goto.

The best answer provided is to place your second loop into a function, and call that function from inside your first loop.

code copied from mquander's response

```
public bool CheckWhatever(int whateverIndex)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        if(whatever[whateverIndex][j]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public void DoubleLoop()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        if(!CheckWhatever(i)) break;
    }
}
```

Though I do feel that using a goto in this case isn't quite as bad as killing kittens.  But it's close.

Comment: How have we all got brain washed?  :)  The resulting structure of this code is more "complex" than using goto (due to the additional 'if-statement' in DoubleLoop).  Splitting the code out may also reduce the set of optimisations that a compiler can make - for example a variable that is local to "CheckWhatever" potentially could have been optimised to be outside the enclosing loop.

Comment: The goto version is much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a better alternative. But one alternative not using `goto` would be modifying the first `for`-loop:

```
for (a = 1; a<sum && result == -1; a++){
```

Then `break` out of the second `for`-loop. That will work assuming the result will never be `-1` after the second `for`-loop has been broken by `break`.

Comment: I don't see this as better. You are making the code harder to read as you are adding more conditions to the test.

Comment: And you're right. As I said, I couldn't think of a better alternative, I just showed a way to avoid the goto loop without altering the code considerably.

Comment: I'd like to add that Alex Martelli's solution is of course better. Encapsulating it in a function is probably the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a `bool found = false` at the top and then add `&& !found` to your for loop conditionals (after `a < sum` and `b < sum`) and then set found to true where your current goto is.  Then make your output conditional on found being true.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a,b,c,sum = 1000;
for (a = 1; a<sum; ++a)
 for (b = 1; b<sum; ++b){
  c = sum-a-b;
  if (a*a+b*b == c*c) sum = -a*b*c;
 }
printf("a: %d\n",a-1);
printf("b: %d\n",b-1);
printf("c: %d\n",c);
printf("Result: %d\n",-sum);
```

Also optimized result out.. :P

Anyway i love gotos!