# goto statement in C#

Tags: c#, goto

I'm writing a function like in C#:

```
public void CountNumber() 
{
       for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
          if(i > 20) {
               goto out1;
          }

          Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);

          out1:
             string hello = "";
       }
}
```

This basically counts the number and if the i is greater than 20 it should not write to console.writeline. it should step over and hit "out1" but the "out1" needs to have a function in the end to compile. It needs to have "string hello = """ to compile. I don't need the "string hello = """. I just want it to do nothing and got the end of the loop. Is there a way to do this without the "string hello = """ that the out1: statement needs? Like:

```
public void CountNumber() 
{
       for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
          if(i > 20) {
               goto out1;
          }

          Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);

          out1:
       }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: invert the logic and toss out the goto

Comment: or don't invert the logic and use break instead of goto.

Comment: Why not using the for statement from 0 to 20 ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This loop could easily be written many other ways - you could just loop while `i<=20` instead of `i<40` (best), or move the `Console.WriteLine` call into the if statement with the if inverted.

However, I'm assuming you're trying to work with a more elaborate scenario in your "real" case.  If that's the case, instead of using `goto`, just use `continue` to skip the rest of the loop:

```
public void CountNumber() 
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      if(i > 20) {
         continue; // Skips the rest of this loop iteration
      }

      Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);
   }
}
```

Similarly, you can use `break` to completely break out of the loop and not process more elements, if that's more appropriate in your real case.

Comment: The natural next question is what to do if you are dealing with nested loops; `break` and `continue` will only work on the innermost loop.  For discussion of this issue, see [How to break out of 2 loops without a flag variable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982595/how-to-break-out-of-2-loops-without-a-flag-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 29):

Though it is absolutely correct to say that there are better ways to solve this problem than to use goto, I note that no one has actually answered your question.

A label must label a *statement*. You want to go to a location that has no statement associated with it. You can either make an empty statement with a single semicolon, or an empty block.

```
    out1:
    ;
}
```

or

```
    out1:
    {}
}
```

But like they say, don't go there in the first place if you can avoid it.

Comment: Is it considered bad form to just put it on one line, (e.g., `out1: ;`)?

Comment: @Brian: It's considered bad form by many people to have a goto at all; a goto to an empty statement is worse, and a goto to an empty statement that puts two almost-identical punctuation characters next to each other is worse still. I would avoid this idiom if possible.

Answer (score 10):

Just invert your condition - also `if...else` might be an alternative. I assume there is other code otherwise you can just change the `for` loop itself to just count up to 20.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
   {
      if(i <= 20) 
      {
          Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);
      }
      //other code
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

There are some other goto-like statements, you should consider using:

- `continue` goes to the next iteration of the current loop.
- `break` leaves the current loop
- `return` exits the current method

You should only consider `goto` if none of the above does what you want. And in my experience that's very rarely the case.

It looks like you want to use `continue` here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `continue` keyword for that:

```
public void CountNumber()  {
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if(i > 20) {
      continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);
  }
}
```

However, consider using the `if` instead:

```
public void CountNumber()  {
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if(i <= 20) {
      Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void CountNumber() 
{
       for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
          if(i > 20) {
              continue;
          }

          Console.WriteLine("hello " + 1);

       }
}
```

Comment: Maybe for instead of foreach?

Comment: Reed Copsey and Guffa did the same :)

Comment: @Shymep: the curious thing that is everyone actually did the same mistake :)

Comment: @Tigran: There is no mystery at all, we all copied the code from the question, and edited it.